# Keyboard listener in C that doesn't need to be typed into the Terminal

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to run a program indefinitely in a background terminal until a certain key combination is pressed by the user (at any point in time, not just at the terminal prompt).

My current idea program (below) is going to spawn a thread which will loop until a certain key is pressed and then exit, but only directly into the terminal. I cannot find a solid way to listen to any keyboard input that does not have to be directly into the terminal.

This is my current code. I purposefully use a thread for the listener since I will have my program continue to do other things in the meantime while the thread is listening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *listen_to_kb();

int main(void)
{
        // Create thread that will listen to keyboard in the background
        pthread_t id;
        pthread_create(&id, NULL, listen_to_kb, NULL);

        /*  
                Do some stuff here while thread is listening
        */
        
        pthread_join(id, NULL);
        return 0;
}

void *listen_to_kb()
{
        // Listen indefinitely for key press
        while (1) {
                char c = getchar(); 
                if (c == 'q') {
                       exit(0); 
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you have just one [xterm] window, you can do this. You may want to look at `termios/tcgetattr/tcsetattr/cfmakeraw` to put the terminal driver into raw mode. Then, you can just poll the keyboard. However, if you have _two_ (or more) windows: (1) winA is your program (2) winB is some other program. You _can't_ . If winB has the keyboard focus, it could be doing `sudo` and if you could monitor/intercept keys typed there, it would be a [grotesque] security violation. You may want to look at `gdm` and/or `gnome-terminal` to see how they handle `<ctrl>-<alt>-<backspace>` or `<alt>-<f2>`.

Comment: With just one window or a callback for a specific sequence `xbindkeys` (per Jerom) is possible. But, again, if another program has the keyboard focus, only a trusted program can monitor an arbitrary key sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## xbindkeys

xbindkeys will run a script on the press of a given key. Create a script that kills a running process or sets some flag in a file for your running program to read and then exit.

Install xbindkeys, then run the following to populate the config file.

```
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

At the bottom of the file add the following lines, with `gedit` replaced with your script.

```
"gedit"
    m:0x10 + c:24
    Mod2 + q
```

Then run `xbindkeys` in your terminal to start the process. You'll have to run `killall xbindkeys` at the end of your script to stop this behavior.

I tested this on my Linux 22.04 machine. Your keybindings could be different; if so, run `xbindkeys -k`, press the desired key, and make sure the code is the same.

I didn't realize this until a couple days later, but xbindkeys seems to start automatically on system restart. Just something to be aware of if you map a more common key than 'q'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `struct input_event` which is defined in `<linux/input.h>`?

You open your /dev/input/eventX, poll for POLLIN then read directly your input_event.

You can check the numerous implementation of evtest available for examples.